# Difference between <%= and <%- in backbone(ASP.net) templates

Tags: asp.net, templates, backbone.js

What is the difference between <%= and <%- that are used into the backbone(ASP.net) templates

Currently as i understand from the really small documentation <%- is the secured version and <%= is the standart.

Comment: Documentation http://underscorejs.org/#template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is:

`<% -` execute code

`<%= -`  explicit output to page

Check out more on [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112)

From the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

If you wish to interpolate a value, and have it be HTML-escaped, use `<%- … %>`

Comment: So there is no difference between <% and <%- ?

Comment: @user3531093:- Here is a list of syntax and there uses:- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112 Also updated my answer!